Desktop Shortcut from .desktop file won't launch (Ubuntu 24.10, GNOME)
There are several similar questions, but none contained answers that worked for me.
I have a .AppImage file and have created a .desktop file which is supposed to launch it. The desktop shortcut shows up in the Activities menu, and I can launch it with gtk-launch, but directly opening it from the Activities menu doesn't work.
Edit: the .desktop file is placed in ~/.local/share/applications .
The Exec attribute in the .desktop file is correct and points to the AppImage.
I have also tried copying it into ~/Desktop and selecting "Allow Launching" from the context menu in the desktop, but this doesn't work either.
Why does launching desktop shortcuts directly differ from gtk-launch, and how can I make it work?

.desktop files should be placed in ~/.local/share/applications.

you may want to watch this LearnLinuxTV Video at time stamp 06:39 where the issue of launching AppImages is discussed.

A half-answer to my own question: https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher seems to be a tool that solves most of the problems.
